# Importing Classified Image in NetLogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

I am working on a project in NetLogo which requires to import an unsupervised classified raster and then move agents to a particular pixel color in raster.

Since netlogo supports .asc file, i have converted my .img file to .asc file in arcmap and when i import the .asc file it opens as black and white image(without the colored pixels which represents classes like water as blue pixel, urban as red pixel and so on).

I need to preserve the color of pixels while importing the raster.

Is there a way to import such raster image ??

Comment: Have you tried displaying the .asc file with some other program? Perhaps is a matter of conversion and not entirely a NetLogo problem.